# dplyr: case_when with multiple substring conditions after first one is met

Tags: r, dplyr, substr, case-when

A beginner here. Trying to use dplyr:case_when which has multiple substring conditions (15-digit string). I realize once a condition for the first row is met its not checking for the other conditions. Would appreciate in correcting this?

```
initialResults <- data %>% mutate(PLANE_TYPE = case_when(
  (substr(AIRLINE_RE,12,1) == "Y" ~ "HLT"), 
  (substr(AIRLINE_RE,4,1) == "Y" ~ "ALA"),
  (substr(AIRLINE_RE,6,1) == "Y" ~ "WTC"),
  TRUE ~ "Unknown"))

    AIRLINE_RE      PLANE_TYPE
1   NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN HLT
2   NNNYNNNNNNNNNNN Unknown
3   NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN HLT
4   YNNNNNNNNNNNNNN Unknown
5   NNNNNYNNNNNNNNN Unknown
```

Desired output

```
    AIRLINE_RE      PLANE_TYPE
1   NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN HLT
2   NNNYNNNNNNNNNNN ALA
3   NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN HLT
4   YNNNNNNNNNNNNNN Unknown
5   NNNNNYNNNNNNNNN WTC
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For each row, `case_when` will return the first clause where the condition is true. So the problem is probably that how `case_when` works does match how you are wanting to use it. But this is difficult to tell without some more details. Please would you add example data, expected output and current output? Taking a look at [mcve] might help.

Comment: Thanks @Simon.S.A. for your reply and advice. I've updated my query with some data, current and expected output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extra details, it looks like the cause might have been `substr`. The input to this function is:

```r
substr(x, start, stop)
```

From your code, it looks like you were using the third argument as the number of characters to return, rather than the character position to stop on (documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substr)).

The following produces your desired output for me:

```r
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(AIRLINE_RE = c("NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN",
                               "NNNYNNNNNNNNNNN",
                               "NNNNNNNNNNNYNNN",
                               "YNNNNNNNNNNNNNN",
                               "NNNNNYNNNNNNNNN"))

data %>% mutate(PLANE_TYPE = case_when(
  substr(AIRLINE_RE,12,12) == "Y" ~ "HLT",
  substr(AIRLINE_RE,4,4) == "Y" ~ "ALA",
  substr(AIRLINE_RE,6,6) == "Y" ~ "WTC",
  TRUE ~ "Unknown"))
```